# Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined during ng build --prod

Tags: angular, build, angular8

I am at the finishing point and I am trying to upload my application to production. I ran the ng build --prod command and I only got one warning message saying:

```
 "WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\app.module.ngfactory.js ->             src\app\app.module.ts"
```

It seems like it is just a warning, but it might be the cause of this error I am not too sure; the main error that I get my in application is:

```
 main-es2015.39c9ec206581527dd6ff.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined
```

This is only in the production build and in my local it works perfect. I have it setup in IIS server.

I read a post that angular doesn't give you all the errors and to run this command and it will give you the error message. I ran it and I did have some errors which I was able to fix.

```
./node_modules/.bin/ngc
```

I am almost there... Any help would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if there are any other data or files I can upload to help pin-point the error.

Not sure if this would be helpful:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TaskComponent } from './task/task.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
//services 
import {TaskService} from './task.service';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';

//material design 
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

//reactive forms
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatPasswordStrengthModule } from '@angular-material-extensions/password-strength';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UpdateTaskComponent } from './update-task/update-task.component';
import { CreateTaskComponent } from './create-task/create-task.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UpdateRecipientComponent } from './update-recipient/update-recipient.component';
import { CreateNewUserComponent } from './create-new-user/create-new-user.component';
import { SidenavService } from './sidenav.service';
import { ManageUsersComponent } from './manage-users/manage-users.component';
import { UpdateUserComponent } from './update-user/update-user.component';
import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from './confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.component';
import { TabDirective } from './ReuseableFunctions/tab-directive';
import { MyReportsGridComponent } from './my-reports-grid/my-reports-grid.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { CdkDetailsRowDirective } from './cdk-details-row.directive';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CdkDetailsRowDirective,
    TaskComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    UpdateTaskComponent,
    CreateTaskComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    UpdateRecipientComponent,
    CreateNewUserComponent,
    ManageUsersComponent,
    UpdateUserComponent,
    ConfirmationDialogComponent,
    TabDirective,
    MyReportsGridComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatPasswordStrengthModule,

    MatGridListModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatMenuModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [UpdateTaskComponent, UpdateRecipientComponent, UpdateUserComponent, ConfirmationDialogComponent],
  providers: [TaskService,AuthService, SidenavService, HeaderComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Your module AppModule is not used anywhere else ?

Comment: It's used in my main.ts file inside this platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err)); 
That's about it and some autogenerated javascript files that I can see

Comment: Are you using server side rendering ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10205

Comment: I have it hosted in an IIS server. I just tested it out and I did ng build without the prod and those files are loading up my project, but the ng build --prod is still not working. I'll read the post deeply.

Comment: Do you get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined" when you do "ng build --prod" or you get the error when you run the application. Do you have any "moduleType" property in your code which is being accessed somewhere in your code? If so, can you please share that code/template/ts?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue .  The root cause for me was my app.module.ts

The below lines was causing a circular dependency. After removing it , I no longer faced this issue

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```